# I am unable to find login with fingerprint & login with faceid options on ubuntu's user setting. My Laptop model is Hp probook 440 g8 notebook PC

Tags: drivers, security, ubuntu-drivers

I just got a new Hp probook 440 g8 notebook PC, which includes a fingerprint scanner. It works fine for Windows.Fingerprint sensor did not detected in Hp probook 440 g8 notebook PC.

Comment: did you follow the instructions in [this official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-fingerprint.html.en) which references v23.10 specifically?